# Custom relationship similar to dependent destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web, model-view-controller

I would like to implement certain relationship between 2 models.

I have 2 models: `quiz` and `question` that have many-to-many relationship.
Quiz model have `quiz_flag` and question model have `question_flag`.

What I want to happen is when `quiz_flag` is changed to true, every question that is in direct relationship (basically every question that is contained within that `quiz`), should also change `question_flag` to true.

Logic is similar to `dependent: :destroy`, but it's a custom function that I want to trigger when `quiz_flag` becomes true.
But how do I specifically do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the callback :before_update inside your model.
I'd do something like this:

```
class Quiz < ApplicationRecord
before_update :update_question_flags, :if => :question_flag_changed?

  def update_question_flags
    self.questons.update_all(question_flag:true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just add additional logic to whatever form/action is responsible for setting quiz.

I.e.:

```
if params[:quiz_flag] #if the quiz_flag params is set to true. 
  @quiz.questions.update_all(question_flag: true)
end
```

Or if it's for multiple controllers, you could use callbacks:

Quiz Model:

```
before_save :some_method #will work before object is saved
```

(works with both create and update, if you just want update use before_update)

```
def some method
 if self.quiz_flag == true
    self.questons.update_all(question_flag:true)
 end
end
```

I would caution you on using callbacks though. It can lead to some messy code that will be difficult to test for later.